# HTML form doesnt work

Tags: php, html, forms

complete newbie in this.

a guy sent me a code for a contact form. the form looks nice, however it is not functioning(pressing submit does nothing). I guessed that the relevant section from the whole code is the one I pasted below. 
how do I turn this into a working form?

```html
<!-- Content -->
<div id="main">
 <div class="wrapper cf">
  <div class="content contact-block cf">
   <h2><i>Contact</i> Us</h2>
   <div class="sidebar-form cf">
    <div class="row"><input id="firstname" type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="FIRST NAME" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="LAST NAME" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="order" type="text" name="order" value="" placeholder="ORDER NUMBER" /></div>
    <div class="row">
     <select id="subject" name="subject">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">SUBJECT</option>
      <option value="1">Received Error Message</option>
      <option value="2">Login Issues</option>
      <option value="3">Billing Questions</option>
      <option value="4">Membership Questions</option>
      <option value="5">Privacy Issues</option>
      <option value="6">Report Abuse</option>
      <option value="7">Legal Department</option>
      <option value="8">Other</option>
      <option value="9">How Do I Access Reports I've Run</option>
      <option value="10">Account Cancellation</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" placeholder="COMMENTS OR QUESTIONS"></textarea></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- // Content -->
```

This is the **contactengine.php** file

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "mymail@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "mymail@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Nice & Simple Contact Form by CSS-Tricks";
$fname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));
$lname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['lname']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$order = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['order'])); 
$subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$comments = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comments'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $fname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $lname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "order: ";
$Body .= $order;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "subject: ";
$Body .= $subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "comments: ";
$Body .= $comments;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: You learn html / php?

Comment: Step 1: Add a `<form>`

Comment: Learn how the code is designed to work before trying to use it, especially when *some guy* gives it to you.

Comment: you are probably right. any good source you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code inside `form` tag.

```html
<!-- Content -->
<form method="post" action="">
<div id="main">
 <div class="wrapper cf">
  <div class="content contact-block cf">
   <h2><i>Contact</i> Us</h2>
   <div class="sidebar-form cf">
    <div class="row"><input id="firstname" type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="FIRST NAME" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lname" value="" placeholder="LAST NAME" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" /></div>
    <div class="row"><input id="order" type="text" name="order" value="" placeholder="ORDER NUMBER" /></div>
    <div class="row">
     <select id="subject" name="subject">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">SUBJECT</option>
      <option value="1">Received Error Message</option>
      <option value="2">Login Issues</option>
      <option value="3">Billing Questions</option>
      <option value="4">Membership Questions</option>
      <option value="5">Privacy Issues</option>
      <option value="6">Report Abuse</option>
      <option value="7">Legal Department</option>
      <option value="8">Other</option>
      <option value="9">How Do I Access Reports I've Run</option>
      <option value="10">Account Cancellation</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" placeholder="COMMENTS OR QUESTIONS"></textarea></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- // Content -->
</form>
```

Comment: OK, done that.what needs to be inside the: `action=""` ?

Comment: @troy it should have your target page url

Comment: OK, I pointed it like so: `<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">`  I found a form in PHP code from http://css-tricks.com/examples/NiceSimpleContactForm.zip and I changed the code of contactengine.php as I managed to understand (cant paste it here, its too long). Im using XAMPP to test it, but Im getting an error: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
Error 404

Comment: added **contactengine.php** file above